# Android virtual device not starting

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb, virtual-device-manager

1. Two days ago my android studio was working well then I don't know
   what happened I got this problem.
2. When I hit the play button before it used to launch the emulator but
   this time it didn't launch.
3. Then I tried to start the virtual device manually going to Android
   Virtual Device Manager but it only says "avd starting" but nothing
   happens.
4. Then I deleted the existing device and created a new virtual device
   but nothing happened.
5. Then I restarted the Android studio deleting all the files in root
   directory of the android studio and started again with default
   settings downloaded all the required files but this time also
   the virtual device didn't start.

Comment: Which OS have you used ?

Comment: windows 10 @HareshChhelana

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question is old. Regardless, for anyone that may experience the same problem; as I had, here is what I did to resolve the issue:

1. Locate the windows "Android SDK Location" which is the path to your emulator:
2. In my case, it is here: [`C:\Users\profile_name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWQNX.png)
3. Try running the device at the command line at the sdk path shown above like this:

   - `sdk_path_from_step_2\emulator -avd "name of device"`
4. If you have the same problem I did, the path was wrong in my system variables
5. To fix it do the following:

   - Open your system properties; (`sysdm.cpl` at a command prompt)
   - Select the Advanced tab
   - Click on the "Environment Variables" tab.
   - Ensure that your have a variable named `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` with the path to your sdk you saw in step 2
   - Add or Update the System Variable to match what you find in Step 2.
   - [In my case it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAnZ8.png)

Comment: How do you run `sdk_path_from_step_2\emulator` if `emulator` is a directory? Is that something that have changed recently? For me it is `sdk_path_from_step_2\emulator\emulator.exe`.